# What is the best way of error handling in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working with simple phoenix elixir application. In this app I'm trying to expose a rest api to save and retrieve data.

In my case, if the primary key (email address ) is a duplicate, my application throws an error.
I need to know the best way to handle this error; either try-catch or any other better solutions.

this is my data save method

```
def post(conn, %{"stooge" => stooge, "name" => name, "email" => email , "password" => password})do
    respond = Repo.insert!(%ApiDb.User{name: name, email: email, stooge: stooge, password: password})
    json conn, respond
  end
```

sample payload

```
{
    "stooge": "moe",
    "name": "Joe",
    "email": "p31111ww11eee32111111134@dmain.com",
    "password":"asdasd"
}
```

models/user.ex

```
defmodule ApiDb.User do
  use ApiDb.Web, :model
  schema "users" do
    field :password, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :stooge, :string
    timestamps()
  end

   @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :email, :password, :stooge])
    |> validate_required([:name, :email, :password])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
  end
end
```

error 
[image]

I tried the try-catch blocks but there was no luck

```
try do
    respond = Repo.insert!(%ApiDb.User{name: name, email: email, stooge: stooge, password: password})
    json conn, respond
rescue 
  e in Ecto.ConstraintError -> IO.puts("An error occurred: ")
end
```

Comment: You should create a `changeset` function in `ApiDb.User`, add `unique_constraint` to it as the error message says, and then use `Repo.insert` in the controller with `case` to handle the error case. Try generating a model with `phoenix.gen.json` in a brand new app and study its source or read http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models (especially `case Repo.insert(changeset) do ...` on that page).

Comment: i have this model 
defmodule ApiDb.User do
  use ApiDb.Web, :model
  schema "users" do
    field :password, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :stooge, :string
    timestamps()
  end
end

Comment: @Dogbert can you guide me with example to my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found nice and easy way to do that

```
 def post(conn, %{"stooge" => stooge, "name" => name, "email" => email , "password" => password})do
    try do
        respond = Repo.insert!(%ApiDb.User{name: name, email: email, stooge: stooge, password: password})
        json conn, respond
    rescue 
      e in Ecto.ConstraintError ->  json conn, (%{"status" => false, "message" => e.message})
    end
  end
```

Comment: It works for a couple of cases, but it becomes tiresome and you end up with ugly code if you have to do this for every action in every controller.  It's not DRY at all.
Can the exception "bubble up"?

Answer (score 5):

Call the ApiDbUser.changeset function, then call Repo.insert with the changeset. It will return tuple with either :ok, or :error

```
def post(conn, params) do
  changeset = ApiDb.User.changeset(%ApiDb.User{}, params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, user} -> 
       # create a render("user.json", params) function in your UserView
       render conn, "user.json", user: user
    {:error, changeset} 
      # create a render("error.json", params) function in your UserView
      render conn, "error.json", changeset: changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: my case phoenix as a api not as front end. btw great reply

Comment: The answer I provided is for an API, not a front end. If you implement a `def render("user.json", %{user: user}), do: user` function in your view, phoenix will automatically encode your JSON response.

Answer (score 2):

After Phoenix 1.3 release there is another way: to user `action_fallback`
Here is an example from the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#action_fallback/1)

```
defmodule MyController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  action_fallback MyFallbackController

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) do
    with {:ok, post} <- Blog.fetch_post(id),
         :ok <- Authorizer.authorize(current_user, :view, post) do

      render(conn, "show.json", post: post)
    end
  end
end
```

It allows to move error handling to fallback controller and reuse it across the app:

```
defmodule MyFallbackController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  def call(conn, {:error, :not_found}) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:not_found)
    |> render(MyErrorView, :"404")
  end

  def call(conn, {:error, :unauthorized}) do
    conn
    |> put_status(403)
    |> render(MyErrorView, :"403")
  end
end
```